# Does the vanilla Qt creator have the C++ std library

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, header-files

essentially what the title says. Will I have to include a .dll to the std C library or can I just write #include  (for input/output) at the top to include the header file.

Comment: Qt creator is an IDE.

Comment: The standard library usually comes with the *compiler*, not the IDE.

Comment: When you install a version of Qt Creator (bundled with mingw) you will have the standard library.

Comment: Right but the IDE/package it comes in all includes the compiler.

Comment: and thankyou @drescherjm , I will add the mingw component to my next redownload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that the C++ std library should always be available with any C++ IDE or framework.

Almost all C++ compilers include the C++ std library, so unless you're working on operating system development or something like that, you can rely on the std library being available. In general, you shouldn't need to do anything special to link to it, as the compiler will automatically link all C++ programs to the C++ std library.

Comment: Thank you! One question on that though, in the visual studios compiler you still have to include the header file <stdWhatever> when you want to write code with that specific library. Would you still have to for the Qt IDE (I believe I have mine setup with a visual studios compiler anyway)

Comment: Yes. You shouldn't expect any standard headers to be automatically by Qt or by your compiler. Even if your preprocessor/compiler makes exceptions, it's bad practice to rely on such things.